# Recibir un dato de un WebService con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quiero consultar un webservice al que envio un dato y recibo un listado de tipo string. He intentado usar la librería soap.js pero no me funciona. ¿ Hay alguna manera de hacerlo desde JavaScript fácilmente sin soap.js?

Este es el código que tengo ahora usando jQuery y soap.js que no me funciona:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./files/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./files/jquery.soap.js"></script>
```

En la cabecera además pongo este código que creo que no se ejecuta ya que no me llega a salir ni el alert !

```
$.soap({
   url: 'http://192.168.0.10:9191/Miservicio.asmx?wsdl',
    method: 'BuscarPoblacion',

    data: {
        codPostal: '08080'
    },

    success: function (soapResponse) {

        // do stuff with soapResponse
        // if you want to have the response as JSON use soapResponse.toJSON();
        // or soapResponse.toString() to get XML string
        // or soapResponse.toXML() to get XML DOM

        alert(soapResponse.toString());
    },
    error: function (SOAPResponse) {
        // show error
    }
 });
```

Añado otra solución en JavaScript con JQuery que tampoco me funciona pero en este caso si que me sale el alert con el mensaje 'error':

```
var servicioURL = 'http://192.168.0.10:9191/Miservicio.asmx';
var soapMsg = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' xmlns:tem='http://tempuri.org/'><soap:Header/><soap:Body><tem:BuscarPoblacion><!--Optional:--><tem:codPostal>08080</tem:codPostal></tem:BuscarPoblacion></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

function OnSuccess(data, status) {
  alert(data.d);
}

function OnError(request, status, error) {
  alert('error');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.support.cors = true;
});
```

y dentro de la etiqueta 'body' del html

```
<script>
  $.ajax({
    url: servicioURL, 
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml", 
    data: soapMsg, 
    processData: false,
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
    success: OnSuccess, 
    error: OnError });
</script>
```

Comment: Brother, necesitamos un poco más de información, qué error te da? Una alternativa fácil es $.get de JQuery

Comment: No me da ningún error, no me llega a salir el alert.

Comment: Tu api recibe el metodo get? si escribes el url http://192.168.0.10:9191/Miservicio.asmx?wsdl en tu navegador, qué te aparece?

Comment: La API funciona bien pues lo he comprobado con el programa SoapUI

Comment: Hay forma de hacer requests soap sin librerías pero son también un infierno, mira esto https://stackoverflow.com/a/11404133/6121568

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer, ya que con el SoapUI funciona, es copiarte el raw request que arma el programa y eso pegarlo como petición del ajax. Eso podría funcionar.

Comment: He copiado el raw request en el segundo código en la variable soapMsg pero no funciona me sale el mensaje del Alert con 'Error'